# how to remove bootstrap css from spree frontend

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, spree

Recently, I tried to remove all instances of Bootstrap from the front end of Spree by overriding frontend_boostrap.css.scss

I have just included this file in app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/frontend_boostrap.css.scss and kept it blank but still application loads bootstrap css. Please guide me how to remove  this from frontend.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add the folders:

```
# app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb then remove bootstrap:

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><%= title %></title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
<%== meta_data_tags %>
<%= canonical_tag(current_store.url) %>
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>

<%# Remove below %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'spree/frontend/all', media: 'screen' %>

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%# Remove below %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'spree/frontend/all' %>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<%= yield :head %>
<%= render 'spree/shared/translations' %>
```

See [Spree's head](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spree/spree/master/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb).

If you're doing this, you have a ton of work to do as few JavaScript codes are appended with bootstrap classes.

Answer (score -1):

Remove  `<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` from your html page.